# How to keep single SQL Server connection instance open for multiple request in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a Web API which contains database insert logic (ado.net) in C#. When multiple users (e.g. 100 users) call the Web API, every time a SQL Server connection is opened and closed for multiple requests. It slows down performance.

How can I keep a single SQL Server connection live for multiple requests? I have to keep SQL connection open only once and close after some time so that during that time it should consider multiple request and insert records in database.

Please suggest.

Comment: How have you *confirmed* that this is affecting performance.  SQL connection pooling is *highly optimized*.  And trying to manage connection pooling yourself is a *famously bad idea*.  Why do you assume that you can optimize it better than it already is?  Where are the performance metrics that you've measured which indicate that is the bottleneck?

Comment: .Net uses connection pooling to optimize this scenario, open/close/dispose connections as and when they are needed, this is best practice.

Comment: How do you know that the connection opening and closing is what takes time? Did you do a performance test? Where's the code for that test? And where's the code you use?

Comment: When you close a connection it just releases it for use in the pool, it doesn't actually close it on the database server, it is internal to ADO.Net.

Comment: I mean to say when multiples calls to web api (>100) increases. it shouldn't slow down performance. I want web api should process 500-1000 request in 1 second. currently it takes 1.5 seconds for 100 request. I read connection pooling but it only applies to current process so when it will only open sql connection once based on pool size. how sql connection pool  will work for multiple request (>500 call means 500 db insertion). please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: An ASP.Net request-response does not happen within its own isolated process rather it happens on a thread within a worker process (application pool) meaning the connection pool is available to all sessions in your application.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

ADO.NET's `SqlConnection` is implementing a connection pool.
This means that when you close or dispose an instance of `SqlConnection`, the underlying connection simply returns to the pool. When another instance of `SqlConnection` is opened, and a connection is available in the connection pool, that connection will be used.
In fact, Microsoft docs page on [SQL Server Connection Pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) clearly states:

> **Caution**
>   We strongly recommend that you always close the connection when you are finished using it so that the connection will be returned to the pool. You can do this using either the Close or Dispose methods of the Connection object, or by opening all connections inside a using statement in C#, or a Using statement in Visual Basic. Connections that are not explicitly closed might not be added or returned to the pool. For more information, see using Statement or How to: Dispose of a System Resource for Visual Basic.

This means that the best practice way of using `SqlConnection` is this:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // your sql stuff goes here...
}
```

BTW, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` and `SqlDataAdapter` also implements the `IDisposable` interface, so they too needs to be used in the context of the `using` statement:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        // prepare command here - parameters and stuff like that

        // either
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

        }

        // or 
        using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zohar. but it will work only for current process which may contain multiple sql connection open/close scenario. I want single sql connection to work for multiple request(>100 times call to web api means everytime different process) in c#. please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @user2638841 See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210258/how-to-keep-single-sql-server-connection-instance-open-for-multiple-request-in-c#comment83402483_48210258) to your question by Alex K.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's easy you just have to keep the connection open and if any readers opened they are closed.

```
var con = new SqlConnection("Your connection String");
   con.open();
   //your code
con.close()//after you have done your executions
```

Have you tried Linq. It does the same thing you want, it keeps the connection alive and i think it'll be easier for you