# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CustDAL.AddNewCust(ref Customer)

Tags: c#, sql

For this code row

```
bool rowsAffected = CustDAL.AddNewCust(ref newCustomer);
```

I get an error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 
>   'CustDAL.AddNewCust(ref Customer)

And the code in the CustDAL looks like

```
 public bool AddNewCust(ref Models.Customer newCustomer)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
        {
            CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}','{4}')", newCustomer.Title, newCustomer.Forename, newCustomer.Surname, newCustomer.Address, newCustomer.PhoneNumber)
        };

        return ExecuteNonQuery(command);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is terrible on a few different levels.

**First**, it's an open door for SQL Injection attacks.
If anyone would set the customer's Title to, say, `Title');DROP TABLE CUSTUMER;--`, care to guess what happens next?
Never concatenate strings with user input to create SQL statement. Instead, use parameterized queries to send the user input to the database safely.
A correct insert statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName(Column1, Column2....Columnn) VALUES(@Param1, @Param2...@Paramn)
```

**Second**, if you add or remove a column from the Customer table, your code will break. Always specify the columns list when writing insert statements.
Imaging adding a new column to the Customer table for middle name. If you do that, your current statement will break, since the number of columns will stop matching the number of values.

**Third**, If any of the string properties of newCustomer contains the ' char you'll get an exception - since your SQL would become something like this:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES('My title isn't that smart', 'My forename',...
```

**Fourth**, you are passing an instance of SqlCommand around, you don't dispose it. 
While it's not terrible not to dispose `SqlCommand` since it does not hold any unmanaged resources, that is an implementation detail. The fact is that it's implementing the `IDisposable` interface, and as such should be disposed. You can read a bit more about that on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350749/does-ado-net-go-overboard-with-idisposable/49353952#49353952). best practice usage of instances that implements the `IDisposable` interface is as a local variable inside a `using` statment -

```
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    //... do command stuff here
}
```

**Fifth**, `DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` returns an int for a reason.
The return value of the `ExecuteNonQuery` is indicating the number of rows effected by the SQL Statement.
If you use a query that tries to insert multiple records, or update multiple records, you might need to know how may records where actually inserted or updated as a result.
Returning bool hides that data from the calling code.

**Sixth**, No point of passing the `newCustomer` parameter by reference, unless the method initializes a new instance of `Models.Customer` and assign it to the `newCustomer` reference.

So a better implementation of your `AddNewCust` method would probably look more like this:

```
public int AddNewCust(ref Models.Customer newCustomer)
{
    var sql = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (Title, Forename, Surname, Address, PhoneNumber) VALUES (@Title, @Forename, @Surname, @Address, @PhoneNumber)";
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(sql))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = newCustomer.Title;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Forename", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = newCustomer.Forename;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = newCustomer.Surname;
        //  fill in the rest of the parameters here...
        return ExecuteNonQuery(command); // change this method to return int...
    };
}
```

All that being said, the cause of the current exception you get is because you try to execute an instance member as if it was a static member - I'm guessing `CustDAL` is the name of the class, and not the name of a reference to an instance of that class.
For more information, read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop)
You should first create an instance of the `CustDAL` class and only then you can access it's non-static members. Since DAL classes should probably be used throughout the application, you should probably have a field containing that reference in the calling class:

```
private CustDAL _custDal;

// in the constructor:

_custDal = new CustDAL();

// when you want to add a new customer:

var rowsAffected = _custDal.AddNewCust(newCustomer);
```