# Do I need to close and dispose the SQLConnection explicitly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, sqlconnection

```
SqlDataReader rdr = null;
con = new SqlConnection(objUtilityDAL.ConnectionString);
using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    try
    {
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Parameter);
        cmd.CommandText = _query;
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

In this above code, sqlconnection is opened inside the managed code. Hence, will the connection object be disposed automatically upon ending the scope of USING?

Comment: Your connection object is not inside the scope of a using statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `Dispose` every *temporary* `IDisposable` instance you create *manually*, i.e. wrap them into `using`:

```
   // Connecton is IDisposable; we create it 
   //   1. manually - new ...
   //   2. for temporary usage (just for the query)
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(objUtilityDAL.ConnectionString)) {
     // Check is redundant here: new instance will be closed 
     con.Open();

     // Command is IDisposable
     using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.Parameters.Add(Parameter);
       cmd.CommandText = _query;

       // Finally, Reader - yes - is IDisposable 
       using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
         // while (rdr.Read()) {...}
       }
     }   
   }
```

Please, notice that

```
   try {
     ...
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
     throw ex;
  }
```

is at least *redundant* (it *does nothing* but rethrow the exception, while loosing stack trace) and that's why can be dropped out

Comment: Thanks so much Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: Do NOT rethrow exception as it, or you'll lose the stack trace information... Use only `throw;`

Answer (score 7):

You have to care about the disposal of `SqlConnection`, since it's a disposable object. You can try this:

```
using(var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(objUtilityDAL.ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        // the rest of your code - just replace con with sqlConnection
    }
}
```

I suggest you replace the `con` with a local variable - if there isn't already (it does not evident from the code you have posted). There is no need for using a class field for this purpose. Just create a local variable, it would be far more clear to track it.

Comment: It looks like that `con` might be a field. I don't suggest using a field in the `using` statement. Because once it got disposed in this method and you try to use the field somewhere else you will get an exeption, because the object got disposed. Wouldn't be using a local variable better to avoid above situation? Moreover a field which gets disposed doesn't even have any advantage versus a local variable. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @L.Guthardt By reading the post a bit fast, I did't notice that this might be a class field :). Well said ! As I have written in my update, I don't think that's a good idea to make use of class field for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you. :) Very nice that you updated your answer to add this information. +1

Comment: Thanks so much Christos. Your point suggesting me to use local variable instead of class variable makes sense as it will get disposed inside the method. I would change the logic. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

In general:

In the .Net framework, nothing gets disposed automatically. Otherwise we wouldn't need the `IDisposable` interface. The garbage collector can only handle managed resources, so every unmanaged resource must be handled in code in the dispose method.

So as a rule, every instance of every class that is implementing the `IDisposable` must be disposed either explicitly by calling it's `Dispose` method or implicitly with the `using` statement.

As best practice, you should strive to use anything that implements the `IDisposable` interface as a local variable inside a using statment:

```
using(var whatever = new SomeIDisposableImplementation())
{
    // use the whatever variable here
}
```

The `using` statement is syntactic sugar. the compiler translates it to something like this:

```
var whatever = new SomeIDisposableImplementation();
try
{
    // use the whatever variable here
}
finally
{
    ((IDisposable)whatever).Dispose();
}
```

Since the `finally` block as guaranteed to run regardless of whatever happens in the `try` block, your `IDisposable` instance is guaranteed to be properly disposed.

With `SqlConnection` specifically, [in order to return the connection object back to the connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210258/how-to-keep-single-sql-server-connection-instance-open-for-multiple-request-in-c/48210460#48210460), you must dispose it when done (the Dispose method will also close the connection, so you don't need to explicitly close it) - So the correct use of `SqlConnection` is **always** as a local variable inside the `using` statement:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // do stuff with con here
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Zohar Peled

Comment: Glad to help :-)