# The ConnectionString property initialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado

Although this question seems like have answers already but my case is different, here's how.

**It works the first time but fails for subsequent requests.**

I'm creating the connection in the main class and passing to the DB class as a dependency in it's constructor and it's meant to be re-used for each call.

```
public class DB
{
    private SqlConnection conn;

    public DB(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public List<Records> GetRecords()
    {
        using (conn){
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Records", conn))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                List<Records> rows = new List<Records>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    rows.Add(new Records(reader.GetString(1)));
                }
                return rows;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Caller class**

```
string connection = $@"
    Data Source=;
    Initial Catalog=;
    Persist Security Info=True;
    User ID={env["DATABASE_USER"]};
    Password={env["DATABASE_PASSWORD"]};";

Db db = new DB(new SqlConnection(connection));
db.GetRecords();
```

> fail:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
>         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has
>   not been initialized.

Comment: Inappropriately reusing `SqlConnection` objects in the mistaken belief that they are expensive to create is common. They're not; an `SqlConnection` object represents a handle to a pooled physical connection. Only the first creation is expensive. There is rarely a good reason to put `SqlConnection` instances in fields, let alone pass them between scopes. The most important argument against reusing connections is that they become unusable if an error occurs, requiring a close. This makes error recovery a nightmare if the connection is shared.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I also realize why I did that in the first place, so that I could mock the dependencies in my unit tests which I've done in other languages, new to csharp so not sure how to approach that.

Comment: Two obvious ways: you can use a LocalDB instance (effectively, keep the database code as it is, and just give it a full featured local database), or refactor the database code in a class that just produces the data, without the caller needing to know that it's coming from a database, and mock that. People occasionally try to go "inbetween" and keep objects from `System.Data` around while you somehow still intercept the physical database access, but if even possible at all, this tends to be much more complicated than the obvious approaches, due to the strong coupling between these classes.

Comment: Furthermore, if your data needs are of rather trivial kind (as they are in this example), consider using a simple ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/) to abstract over the database. This saves you a ton of boilerplate code in serializing objects, and methods that produce `IEnumerable<...>` instances are trivial to mock.

Comment: Thanks, I like the second choice, meaning I'd create a `FakeDB` class instead of `DB` class and just generate the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I guess the problem is the

```
using(conn)
```

when the using is closed, the SqlConnection will be disposed.
so when you call again *db.GetRecords();*,
*conn.Open()* is not initialized. -> exception

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `SQLConnection` as a field, but as a local variable inside the method. Change your class to take in the connection string inside it's parameter instead of an instance of `SqlConnection` and initialize it in any method that use it:

```
public class DB
{
    private string connectionString;

    public DB(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public List<Records> GetRecords()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Records", conn))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                List<Records> rows = new List<Records>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    rows.Add(new Records(reader.GetString(1)));
                }
                return rows;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more details, [read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210460/3094533)

Comment: Can I just keep the connection open and re-use the requests? Will that be inefficient, if then why will it be inefficient. The only reason I can think of it perhaps it will queue all the calls, and each request has to wait for the earlier one to finish, right?

Comment: @AppDeveloper: a connection supports no more than one active command (unless Multiple Active Result Sets is used, which has its own caveats) and a command will not return until it has completed, so whether you're reusing a connection or closing and re-opening it has no bearing on that.

Comment: The connection pool ensures that disposing and re-creating the connection is a very cheap process. the link at the bottom of my answer explains that.